# Rails Model Validation using Unless

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, model, proc

I have the following model with subscriptions for classes

```
create_table "subscriptions", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "course_id"
    t.datetime "date_subscription_start"
    t.datetime "date_subscription_end"
    t.string   "subscription_type"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

I want to make it so users are able to subscribe to the same class again if they, for some reason, want to retake it. My logic is that it should only be possible to sign up for a class if the date_subscription_end date of the class / user combination has already passed at the time of the new creation. If at the time of creation a Subscription with the same user_id and course_id exists that has a subscription_end date in the future it should be rejected because it means the user is still taking that course.

So something like this:

```
validates :user_id,
  uniqueness: {
    scope: :course_id,
    message: "User is already subscribed to this course"
  },
  unless: Proc.new { |a|
   Subscription.where(user_id: a.user_id, course_id: a.course_id) &&
     Subscription.where('date_subscription_end < ?', Time.now)
  }
```

Basically rails has to go through the subscriptions table, find all subscriptions with the same primary keys and check their date_subscription_end attributes. I feel like I'm close but missing something fundamental.

Thanks!
Jean

Edit: For some reason the "Hello!" greeting at the top of the post gets removed

Comment: I would also like to add that using `unless` is actually considered a bad practice in the Rails and Ruby community. See these syntax style guides: https://github.com/bbatsov/rails-style-guide  https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First the Proc looks incorrect, as far as I can see the Proc returns a truthy value, as soon as the user had a subscription and **some** user (not necessarily `a.user_id`) subscribed **any** course (not  necessarily `a.course_id`)

Second the unless needs to be an if and be part of the options hash for the uniqueness validation.

So the following code should work:

```
validates :user_id,
  uniqueness: {
    scope: :course_id,
    message: "User is already subscribed to this course",
    if: Proc.new { |a|
      Subscription.where(user_id: a.usr_id, course_id: a.course_id)
        .where('date_subscription_end >= ?', Time.now).exists?
    }
  }
```

This way you hit the database only once and your code doesn't need to instantiate all matching subscriptions like it does if you just run `.where(…)`

**UPDATE**:

the condition for the `date_subscription_end` should be: `'date_subscription_end >= ?', Time.now`

Comment: Hey jigfox, thank for the reply, it still doesn't completely work for me. When I create the first subscription give it date_subscription_end of Time.now, then a second one with Time.now + 1.days both save(which is correct) but now if I create a third Subscription with Time.now + 10.days this one also saves...it shouldn't though because the Subscription with date_subscription_end of Time.now + 1.day is still active.

Comment: I think the above answer is correct if you change the unless to if. The current version goes identifies the already existing record and if one of them has date_subscription_end > Time.now it DOES NOT enforce the validation, which is the exact opposite of what is intended. I tested it with if and it seems to be working fine.